# QML equivalent of QPainterPathStroker

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create an outline of a path in QML. I read that QPainterPathStroker is able to do this, but it is not in QML. What is the QML equivalent of QPainterPathStroker?

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) QML type is the closest one. You can see Canvas examples [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-canvas-example.html).